# Robocopy, how to log only errors?

Tags: windows, robocopy

Will the options `/nfl /ndl` be enough and not exclude errors too?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Besides `/nfl` (no list of file names) and `ndl` (no list of directory names) there are some other switches to exlude things from the output.
These are:

- `ns` (no file sizes)
- `nc` (no file classes)
- `np` (no status)
- `njh` (no job header)
- `njs` (no job summary)

If you want to write your log into a text file, your command should look like this:

```
robocopy [source] [destination] /nfl /ndl /njh /njs /ns /nc /np >> log.txt
```

Comment: Robocopy also has options: `/LOG:filename` to specify where to write the log file, `/LOG+:filename` to append to an existing log file, and `/TEE` to write the log to a file while also displaying it to the screen.